# Deep NN with positive partial derivative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, train

Let's assume we are given a FFNN of type
$$F: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad (x_1,...,x_{n+1}) \mapsto y$$
We assume the generic architecture (of depth $H$)
$$a^{l+1}=\sigma(a^{l}), \quad a^l=W^l a^{l-1}+b^l, \quad l=1,...,H$$
where $\sigma$ is the activation function, $a^1=(x_1,...,x_{n+1})$ and $a^H=y$.

---

**My question is the following:** Is there a way to modify the architecture above such that $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_{n+1}}>0 $$

1. I don't want to use regularization. I directly want to modify the architecture.
2. The FFNN should still be a universal approximator for all functions with the restriction above (in an appropriate limit).
3. If it is easier to first design such an architecture with one hidden layer, I will also accept it as an answer.